# Iterating through values to insert... or another way? SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-insert

**Addtional Question:**
I cannot alias the ETL.Dim_Status in the INSERT statement ... so this leads me to believe that the insert into and the select/from/leftjoin/where are two separate statments... So why cant I put the insert into beneath everything??

Are they two separate statements or are they one? If they are one, then why can't I use an alias in the insert into portion?

I the select a subquery?... Then why isn't it in parentheses?

---

So if I try to run this, then I get an error telling me that the Sub-Query returned more than one value. I am aware of this, I need all those values to be inserted.

```
INSERT INTO ETL.Dim_Status ([Status]) 
VALUES(
          --- I need to iterate through each of the new distinct values 

            (
            SELECT DISTINCT 
                I.[Status] 
            FROM 
                dbo.Invitee I
            LEFT JOIN
                ETL.Dim_Status S
                ON  I.[Status] = S.[Status]
            WHERE 
                S.[Status] IS NULL
            )

   );
```

Could I make this a set based operation rather than inserting the values row by row?

I've tried a cursor, but I don't even know if I put everything in the right place:

```
  DECLARE insertNewStatus CURSOR    
  INSERT INTO ETL.Dim_Status ([Status]) 
  VALUES(
      --- I need to iterate through each of the distinct values 
          FOR
             ( 
             SELECT DISTINCT 
                I.[Status] 
             FROM 
                dbo.Invitee I
             LEFT JOIN
                ETL.Dim_Status S
                ON  I.[Status] = S.[Status]
             WHERE 
                S.[Status] IS NULL
             )
         OPEN insertNewStatus
         FETCH NEXT FROM insertNewStatus

   );
```

Comment: After iterating what you are trying to achieve? What is your input and what is your expected output to be stored using insert? Most of the scenarios does not require iteration

Comment: The first one is a 'set based operation' it will insert all values that are returned by the SELECT statement. You just have incorrect syntax

Comment: I am bit confuse with what you actually trying to achieve. But updated my answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
INSERT INTO ETL.Dim_Status ([Status])      
SELECT DISTINCT I.[Status] 
FROM dbo.Invitee I
     LEFT JOIN ETL.Dim_Status S ON  I.[Status] = S.[Status]
 WHERE S.[Status] IS NULL
```

***Update*** - if you trying to add the status from Invitee, which are not already in ETL.Dim_Status

```
   INSERT INTO ETL.Dim_Status ([Status])    
   SELECT DISTINCT [Status] 
   FROM dbo.Invitee 
   WHERE [Status] NOT IN ( SELECT DISTINCT [Status] FROM ETL.Dim_Status)
```

See more about [Adding Rows by Using INSERT and SELECT](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188263(v=sql.105).aspx)

Answer (score 2):

Just remove `values` keyword, sql operation are set operations.
It's a standard SQL syntax.

```
INSERT INTO ETL.Dim_Status ([Status]) 
SELECT DISTINCT 
    I.[Status] 
FROM 
    dbo.Invitee I
LEFT JOIN
    ETL.Dim_Status S
    ON  I.[Status] = S.[Status]
WHERE 
    S.[Status] IS NULL
```